# Converting dynamic type (DynamicJsonObject) to concrete type objects with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, casting, automapper

In a CMS, I'm trying to load "Widgets" via a type variable and use AutoMapper to create the ViewModel instance to use in a partial view.

```
var data = Json.Decode(jsonData);

            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                var d = data[i];

                CmsWgtManager.WidgetType type = Enum.Parse(typeof(CmsWgtManager.WidgetType), d.WidgetType);
                Type modelType = type.GetModelTypeValue();

                var Wgt = Activator.CreateInstance(modelType);

                //these are created externally, just included them here for explanation purposes
                Mapper.CreateMap<dynamic, CmsWgtContentVM>()
                    .ForMember(x => x.Header, o => o.ResolveUsing(s => s.Header));

                Mapper.CreateMap<dynamic, CmsWgtTileStripVM>()
                    .ForMember(x => x.Name, o => o.ResolveUsing(s => s.Name));

                Mapper.CreateMap<dynamic, CmsWgtTileVM>()
                    .ForMember(x => x.Header, o => o.ResolveUsing(s => s.Header));                    


                var widget = new object();
                widget = Mapper.Map(d, Wgt);

                //if (i == 0)
                //{
                //    widget = Mapper.Map<dynamic, CmsWgtContentVM>(d, Wgt as CmsWgtContentVM);
                //}
                //if (i > 0 && i < 3)
                //{
                //    widget = Mapper.Map<dynamic, CmsWgtTileStripVM>(d, Wgt as CmsWgtTileStripVM);
                //}

                widgets.Add(widget as IWgtVM);
            }
```

This will work for the first iteration. On the second, the type changes and I receive a casting error ->
`Unable to cast object of type 'Domain.ViewModels.CmsComponents.CmsWgtTileStripVM' to type 'Domain.ViewModels.CmsComponents.CmsWgtContentVM'.`

Part of the Json (first two items) is below.

```
   {  
  "WidgetType":"Content",
  "Header":"Community Development",
  "Content":"<p><strong>The objective of Place is one and the same: to create a healthy community.</strong> Having a healthy community directly affects the ability to supply services needed by both residents and businesses. Place utilizes Community Development grant programs through the and other sources.<br class=\"k-br\"></p><p>Visit our <a href=\"#\">News &amp; Media</a> page on this website for recently announced grant opportunities.<br class=\"k-br\"></p>",
  "Image":"/Files/Images/about%20section/content-community-dev.jpg",
  "Theme":"None",
  "DefaultView":"Components/WgtContent",
  "ModelFields":"[\"Header\",\"Content\",\"Image\",\"Theme\",\"DefaultView\",\"ModelFields\"]"
   },
   {  
      "WidgetType":"TileStripMedium",
      "Name":"Main Sections",
      "Items":[  
         {  
            "Header":"Territory Map",
            "Content":"<p>View Place territory map from our County Engineer.<br class=\"k-br\"></p><p><img alt=\"\" src=\"/Files/images/about%20section%2Fcontent-territory-map.jpg\"><br></p>",
            "TileLink":"",
            "TileLinkTarget":"",
            "Theme":"GoldAlt",
            "ModelFields":"[\"Header\",\"Content\",\"TileLink\",\"TileLinkTarget\",\"Theme\",\"ModelFields\",\"DefaultView\",\"CustomEditor\"]",
            "DefaultView":"",
            "CustomEditor":""
         },
         {  }
      ],
      "DefaultView":"",
      "CustomEditor":"",
      "ModelFields":"[\"Header\",\"Content\",\"TileLink\",\"TileLinkTarget\",\"Theme\",\"ModelFields\",\"DefaultView\",\"CustomEditor\"]"
   }
```

Comment: hmmm... interesting problem you got there...